# How to create a PPA for Electron app

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, electron, electron-builder

I have built an electron app using electron-react-biolerplate .
How to create a ppa (launchpad) for an electron app ? 
Is there any documentation available for this ??

Answer (score 3):

General steps needed are:

1. Create a .deb package
2. Create a PPA
3. Add your .deb package to your PPA

There are some modules that can help you, like:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-installer-debian

The second one lets you create a .deb package. When you have a .deb package here is a tutorial on how to have a PPA with that:

- https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA

For more info see:

- https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-distribution/
- https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks , for the answer , the packaging part is already done i have the deb packages for 2 and 64 bit. Let me check the launchpad thing... @rsp